# Listening for events from any socket on Socket IO

Tags: node.js, socket.io

How can I listen to an event on the entire server and get the socket passed in on each call instead of having to generate and store new state data for every socket? Or is it not that expensive resource-wise?

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    //do stuff here and make variables 
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
    socket.on('message', function(){
        console.log('user sent message', JSON.stringify(arguments,null,2));
        //handle the message here.
    });
});
```

Instead, I just want to do this:

```
io.on('message', function(socket){
    console.log('io on message' , arguments);
});
```

Comment: By doing the method described in the first code block, you are listening to an event on the entire server and you are getting the socket passed in on each call. There's no real difference between how it actually works and how you want it to work.

Comment: My main question is memory consumption. Which might not be a problem anyway.